# Do Gaussian Processes exist outside of regression and classification?

Tags: gaussian-process

I'm familiar with Gaussian Process regression, it's a powerful tool for fitting non-linear functions while quantifying confidence in predictions. Likewise, I've read that GP classification exists as well. My question is- do GPs exist outside of some downstream task (regression, classification, etc.)? Or is it that a GP would make no sense without some downstream task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Many common Random processes are Gaussian processes: white noise, random walk etc. Their applications are uncountable.
- For other downstream tasks there are variants of Gaussian processes:
  Gaussian processes for sensitivity analysis (based on Gaussian process regression); Unsupervised learning and Deep GP [[1](http://gpss.cc/gpss19/program)]
- Due to their flexibility and availability of approximate inference, we can define many models using as the base Gaussian processes, see heteroscedastic GPs [[2](https://openreview.net/forum?id=BJNsBoWdWB)] and multi-fidelity GPs [[3](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v54/zaytsev17a.html)] as two examples.

Comment: Tangentially related- Is the GP unique among stochastic processes due to its kernel/conditioning technique for regression? I haven't heard of Poisson Process Regression (not to say it isn't a thing.) But seems that GP is somewhat off in its own camp compared to other stochastic processes.

Comment: @jbuddy_13 GP is unique in two ways. 1. You should apply a tool if it is suitable. Poisson processes and their generalization Hawkes processes there are a number of articles related to modeling of event sequences (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.09291). Dirichlet process was also a thing for some applications in ML. But I think that conditional distributions don't make sense for prediction in this case. 2. It  should be easy to use. For GP almost all formulas are analytical, what is not the case for any non-Gaussian assumption.